# Непонятен алгоритм программы "Ханойские башни"

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Коллеги, объясните, пожалуйста, как работает код программы "Ханойские башни".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
void Towers(int number, int from, int to, int free)
{   
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    if(number!=0)
    {
        Towers(number-1, from, free, to);
    cout<<"\n  Снимаем "<<number<<"-й диск с "<<from<<"-го стержня и одеваем его на "<<to<<"-й стержень";      
    Towers(number-1,  free, to, from);
    }
}
void main()   
{ 
    Towers(3, 1, 3, 2);
    cout<<"\n  ";
}
```

- "number" - это колличество дисков.
- "from"   - это стержень с которого переносим все диски.
- "to"     - это стержень на который переносим все диски.
- "free"   - это третий стержень.

А это результат в консольном окне:

> `Снимаем 1-й диск с 1-го стержня и одеваем его на 3-й стержень.
> Снимаем 2-й диск с 1-го стержня и одеваем его на 2-й стержень.
> Снимаем 1-й диск с 3-го стержня и одеваем его на 2-й стержень.
> Снимаем 3-й диск с 1-го стержня и одеваем его на 3-й стержень.
> Снимаем 1-й диск с 2-го стержня и одеваем его на 1-й стержень.
> Снимаем 2-й диск с 2-го стержня и одеваем его на 3-й стержень.
> Снимаем 1-й диск с 1-го стержня и одеваем его на 3-й стержень.`

Что я здесь понял, это что в начале работы функции она тут же рекурсивно вызывает 
саму себя столько раз, сколько верно условие "if" и каждый раз от "number" отнимается
единица, доходит до "number==1", и далее выводится первая строка на консоли. Потом 
снова рекурсивный вызов функции, с аргументами расположенными в другом порядке и туман...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте произвести операцию с физическими объектами (кольцами, полосками бумаги или чем-то ещё). Идея простая: чтобы перенести `n` колец с одного стержня на другой, надо `n-1` перенести с него на свободный (первый рекурсивный вызов), перенести n-ное кольцо на целевой стержень (`cout`), затем `n-1` со свободного перенести на целевой (второй рекурсивный вызов). При вызове назначения колец `from, to, free` меняются, можно добавить вывод их значений при перестановке для наглядности. Т.о. условие не класть больше кольцо на меньшее соблюдается.
UPD
В принципе три отладочных печати в самой процедуре. Правда насколько это поможет, мне теперь уже неясно. Для первого вызова (перенос колец выше нижнего на вспомогательный), для переноса нижнего кольца (существующий cout) и возврата меньших колец с вспомогательного на целевой.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void Towers(int number, int from, int to, int free)
{

     if(number!=0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "%2d%3d%3d%3d/1\n", number-1, from, free, to);
         Towers(number-1, from, free, to);
         fprintf(stderr, "%2d%3d%3d%3d\n", number, from, to, free);
         cout<<"\n  Снимаем "<<number<<"-й диск с "<<from<<"-го стержня и одеваем его на "<<to<<"-й стержень";      
         fprintf(stderr, "%2d%3d%3d%3d/2\n", number-1, free, to, from);
         Towers(number-1,  free, to, from);
     }
}
int main() { 
    cerr << " n  f  r  t" << endl;
    Towers(3, 1, 3, 2);
    cout<<"\n  ";
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод (/1 и /2 -- вызовы Tower):

```
 n  f  r  t
 2  1  2  3/1
 1  1  3  2/1
 0  1  2  3/1
 1  1  3  2
 0  2  3  1/2
 2  1  2  3
 1  3  2  1/2
 0  3  1  2/1
 1  3  2  1
 0  1  2  3/2
 3  1  3  2
 2  2  3  1/2
 1  2  1  3/1
 0  2  3  1/1
 1  2  1  3
 0  3  1  2/2
 2  2  3  1
 1  1  3  2/2
 0  1  2  3/1
 1  1  3  2
 0  2  3  1/2
```

Для доказательства по индукции: перенос одного кольца -- просто переложить. Перенос двух -- перенести верхнее на резервный, перенести нижнее на целевой, перенести верхнее с резервного на целевой. Перенос нескольких -- перенести верхние на вспомогательный штырь, перенести само кольцо number, затем перенести с вспомогательного на целевой. Поскольку выше находятся кольца диаметром меньше, то их перенос правила задачи не нарушает.

Comment: Уважаемый, alexlz, это мне понятно. Непонятно другое. Каким образом
в консольное окно(консоль выложил) выводятся, например номера 
дисков, первая строка в консоли понятна(описал когда задавал вопрос)
Вторая строка: "снимаем 2-й диск...", откуда цифра 2 ит.д., я не 
вижу этого в коде.

Comment: Значение формального параметра number. Он соответствует глубине стека рекурсивных вызовов процедуры Towers. Т.е. на каждом уровне вы знаете, какое кольцо переносится в теле процедуры (вывод на cout). Вызов самого верхнего уровня (для переноса всех дисков) для вашего примера -- number==3. К этому моменту все кольца выше уже перенесены первым рекурсивным вызовом Towers на штырь free (в вызове на месте free стоит исходное to и наоборот). А второй вызов переносит все кольца с free на to с вспомогательным from. Пока лучше объяснить не получается. Рекомендуется распечать таблицу значений в процессе

Comment: Alexlz, да, да таблица нужна, а как ее сделать? Я пытался по ходу кода вставлять cout-ы,
но ничего не дало, да и вставлять их особо некуда. Отладчик тоже не показывает.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Alexlz, добрый день(не хватает знаний), что такое fprintf(stderr, ...)?

Comment: Форматный вывод из Сишной библиотеки. Прототип -- в stdio.h. Первый параметр -- поток, второй -- формат, остальные -- значения для вывода по заданному формату. В iostream обращение к stderr осуществляется через cerr.