# Снова об алгоритме "Ханойские башни"

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день. Я задавал здесь 19 января [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72364/) об алгоритме "Ханойские башни". Мне ответил @alexlz (спасибо) следующее:

> Значение формального параметра number. Он соответствует глубине стека рекурсивных вызовов процедуры Towers. Т.е. на каждом уровне вы знаете, какое кольцо переносится в теле процедуры (вывод на cout). Вызов самого верхнего уровня (для переноса всех дисков) для вашего примера -- number==3. К этому моменту все кольца выше уже перенесены первым рекурсивным вызовом Towers на штырь free (в вызове на месте free стоит исходное to и наоборот). А второй вызов переносит все кольца с free на to с вспомогательным from. Пока лучше объяснить не получается. Рекомендуется распечать таблицу значений в процессе

Теперь понятно какое кольцо переносится на каждом уровне. При каждом новом рекурсивном вызове функции от переменной number отнимается единица, а при возврате из стека
на каждом уровне переменная number становится на единицу больше. Теперь мне непонятно другое, первый рекурсивный вызов вновь вызывает сам себя пока верно условие 'if'.
прикаждом новом рекурсивном вызове, в списке параметров функции изменяется переменная number(-1), но порядок расположения переменных from, free, to остается тот же. Получается при выходе из стека на каждом уровне изменяется только переменная number,
а остальные переменные остаются в том же порядке?

Comment: >но порядок расположения переменных from, to, free остается тот же.

Порядок как раз изменяется:

    void Towers(int number, int from, int to, int free)
    ...
    Towers(number-1, from, free, to);
    ...
    Towers(number-1,  free, to, from);

Comment: Этот вопрос подробно изложен по метке "алгоритмы" за 19 января.

Comment: insolor, ей богу не вижу этого, вижу что Towers(number-1, from, free, to) вызывает саму себя с тем же порядком, меняется только number.

Comment: вдогонку cout впервые срабатывает в теле Towers(number-1, from, free, to)
Извините ошибка в вопросе, написал -- " порядок расположения from, to, free -- неправильно, имел ввиду -- from, free, to.

Comment: Ошибку в вопросе исправил.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ок, еще раз:

> но порядок расположения переменных from, to, free остается тот же.

Где же порядок остается таким же, если:

- В формальных параметрах сначала идет **from**, потом **to**, потом **free**
- В первом рекурсивном вызове: сначала **from**, потом **free**, а потом уже **to**
- Во втором вызове: **free**, **to**, **from**

P.S. в вопросе с самого начала порядок был правильный - как в формальных параметрах

**UPD.** Начнем с самого начала. Задача - перенести 4 кольца с 1 стержня на 3 через 2:

```
Towers(4, 1, 3, 2);
```

Разбиваем на подзадачи:

- Перенести 3 кольца с 1 на 2 стержень через 3 (`Towers(3,1,2,3)`)
- Перенести оставшееся кольцо с 1 на 3 стержень
- Перенести 3 кольца со 2 на 3 стержень через 1 (`Towers(3,2,3,1)`)

Точно так же рекурсивно разбиваем 1 подзадачу:

- Перенести 2 кольца с 1 на 3 стержень через 2 (`Towers(2,1,3,2)`)
- Перенести оставшееся кольцо с 1 на 2 стержень
- Перенести 2 кольца с 3 на 2 через 1 (`Towers(2,3,2,1)`)

Аналогично разбиваем 2 подзадачу, и так до тех пор, пока все не сведется к перемещению отдельных колец.

**UPD2.** Ок. Заново.

```
I. Вызываем Towers(3,1,3,2); (команда перенести 3 кольца с 1 стержня на 3 через 2)
 II. Рекурсивный вызов Towers(2,1,2,3); (команда перенести 2 кольца с 1 стержня на 2 через 3)
  III. Рекурсивный вызов Towers(1,1,3,2); (перенести 1 кольцо с 1 стержня на 3)
    IV. Переносим 1 кольцо с 1 стержня на 3
  III. Переносим 1 кольцо с 1 стержня на 2
  III. Рекурсивный вызов Towers(1,3,2,1); (перенести 1 кольцо с 3 стрежня на 2)
    IV. Переносим 1 кольцо со 2 стержня на 3
  III. Результат: 1 кольцо осталось на 1 стержне, в других на 2 стержне
 II. Переносим 1 кольцо с 1 стержня на 3
 II. Рекурсивный вызов Towers(2,2,3,1); (перенести 2 кольца со 2 стержня на 3 через 1)
  III. Рекурсивный вызов Towers(1,2,1,3); (перенести 1 кольцо со 2 стержня на 1)
    IV. Переносим 1 кольцо со 2 стержня на 1
  III. Переносим 1 кольцо со 2 стержня на 3
  III. Рекурсивный вызов Towers(1,1,3,2); (перенести 1 кольцо с 1 стержня на 3)
    IV. Переносим 1 кольцо с 1 стержня на 3
 II. Результат: 3 кольца на 3 стержне
```

Для простоты вызовы с n=0 пропущены, т.к. смысловой нагрузки не несут. Римские цифры обозначают уровень рекурсивного вызова.

Comment: Да, но я вижу(аргументы в функцию(3, 1, 3, 2))
первый рекурсивный вызов:
функция Towers(number-1, from, free, to)вызвана, 
следующ. шаг проверка условия 'if',
следующ. шаг вызов Towers(number-1, from, free, to),
следующ. шаг проверка условия 'if',
следующ. шаг вызов Towers(number-1, from, free, to),
и так до конца стека, каждый раз отнимая от number единицу.
доходим до number=0, функция с нолем не срабатывает и идет возврат
в вызвавшую функцию, где number=1,
следующ. шаг cout<< 1 диск << c 1 стержня << на 2 стержень.
НЕПРАВИЛЬНО. При формальном number=3, 1 диск с первого нужно на
3 стержень.

Comment: Кстати для формального number=2, алгоритм работает корректно. Я вот только подумал нужно проследить алгоритм при формальном number=4,
то есть тоже с четным колличеством колец, может всплывет чего.

Comment: Чет я ничего не понял. Алгоритм понимаю, пробую по нему переставлять кольца - все правильно. А то что вы пишете в упор не пойму)

Comment: insolor, если понимаете алгоритм, напишите пож. мне пошагово, каждую строчку, что после чего происходит.Спасибо.

Comment: В моем ответе все написано. Как еще объяснить я не знаю. Видимо, вы еще не познали рекурсию)

Comment: Вспоминайте из курса математики "доказательство по индукции". Чтобы перенести одно кольцо с 1го штыря на 2й, вы просто переносите его. Чтобы перенести 2 кольца с 1го на 2й вы переносите (n-1) с 1го на свободный 3й, затем переносите 2 n-ное второе кольцо с 1го на 2й, а далее переносите (n-1) колец с 3го на 2й. В качестве вспомогательного  можно использовать свободный штырь, поскольку если там есть кольца, то они большего диаметра и класть на них меньшие можно по условию задачи. А индукция -- единственный приём, который помогает справиться с итерациями и рекурсией (кажется Дейкстра писал)

Comment: Добрый день. Друзья, я понимаю рекурсию на примере нахождения факториала, я понимаю в Ханойских башнях, что для решения задачи 
нужно решить несколько подзадач, в самой игре ЛЕГКО, с минимальным колличеством ходов переставляю 6 дисков, 63 хода и используя решения подзадач. Я не ппонимаю данный код.

Comment: Я не понимаю данный код. Внутри первого рекурсионного вызова функции с данными параметрами, после проверки условия 'if',
следует рекурсионный вызов этой функции с теми же параметрами, уменьшается только номер диска на единицу, и так далее пока номер
диска не станет равным нулю. И все эти  вызванные функции с одинаковым на бором параметров. При возврате из стека, при колличестве диков number=3, первый же cout выводит ошибку, вернее 
по моим исследованиям должна быть ошибка(код-то сам по себе правильный)
При number=2 работа по моим исследованиям нормальная.

Comment: Вопрос: ЧТО ПРОИСХОДИТ ВНУТРИ ПЕРВОГОГ РЕКУРСИОННОГО ВЫЗОВА.
То что вижу я -- неправильно.

Comment: Какой конкретно перенос вы считает неправильным? тут вот последовательность `:
1. 1d 1 -> 3
2. 2d 1 -> 2
3. 1d 3 -> 2
4. 3d 1 -> 3
5. 1d 2 -> 1
6. 2d 2 -> 3
7. 1d 1 -> 3`

Comment: Здесь при пирамиде из двух дисков все нормально работает.Если три ди-
ска, первый вывод cout уменя получается 1d  1 -> 2, т.е. from, free, to. По другому попробую: первый рекурсионный вызов запускает в работу
функцию с параметрами from, free, to. Внутри этой функции 1 строка -
это проверка условия if, 2 строка -- это вновь рекурсионный вызов функции с параметрами from, free, to, внутри уже этой функции 
1 строка - проверка условия if, 2 строка -- это вновь рекурсионный вызов функции с параметрами from, free, to и так до конца стека, при выходе из стека первый вывод cout -- это from, free, to.

Comment: Опять не понимаю. Есть текст из предыдущего вопроса. Компилируем, запускаем. Получаем то, что я привёл. О чём идёт речь?

Comment: Вы не понимаете меня, я не понимаю вас. Попробуйте расписать пошагово, что происходит внутри первого рекурсионного вызова, я думаю что пойму. Дело в том, что я много искал в интернете ответ на мой вопрос -- не нашел. А вот вопросы подобные моему, народ задает.
Если свашей помощью я пойму суть, я постараюсь поподробней расписать ответ именно на мой вопрос, как его вижу я и выложу его здесь и на других сайтах(сославшись на вас). Я думаю немалая польза будет кому-то. Нужно расписать пошагово, что происходит внутри первого рекурсионного вызова. Спасибо.

Comment: Поконкретнее. В ответе на предыдущий вопрос я приводил таблицу вызовов Tower и переноса колец. Это не то, с чем сейчас непонятки? Там 20 строк.

Comment: Добрый день. По таблице вызовов:   
III. Рекурсионный вызов Towers(1,1,3,2) здесь я не вижу как, каким путем попали эти параметры попали в эту функцию(кроме первой единицы). Параметры правильные, это понятно, но как они там оказываются, это параметры другого вызова этой функции(кроме первой единицы). 
Понимаю так, что если функция вызывается РЕКУРСИВНО, к ней прилагаются свои, родные параметры, которые мы видим при ее вызове .

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Первый (текстуально) рекурсивный вызов Towers меняет местами to и free. Т.е. (для 3х колец) to-free: 3-2 -> 2-3 -> 3-2.

Comment: Да, да, это понятно. Мой вопрос по вашей таблице вызовов, по рекурсионному вызову под римской цифрой III.

Comment: Таблица вызовов моя)

Объясняю: Towers(3,1,3,2) (**to** = 3, **free** = 2) вызывает Towers(2,1,2,3) (**to** стало равно 2, **free** = 3), которая вызывает Towers(1,1,3,2) (**to** = 3, **free** = 2).

Comment: Ну таблицу с римскими цифрами писал не я, а @insolor. Причём прокомментирован Towers(1,1,3,2) как перенос с 1->2 (д.б. 1->3). Или интересует завершающий вызов?

Comment: Упс, исправил.

Comment: Добрый день. 
Таблица вызовов моя)
Объясняю: Towers(3,1,3,2) (to = 3, free = 2) вызывает Towers(2,1,2,3) (to стало равно 2, free = 3), которая вызывает Towers(1,1,3,2) (to = 3, free = 2).

Да, это видно в результате работы программы, в консольном окне, но в коде нет вызова с параметрами (1,1,3,2).

Comment: Извините, если есть, то как же нет? Т.е. где (1,1,3,2) есть? где (в коде) (1,1,3,2) нет?

Comment: @Ключ, в каждом следующем по глубине рекурсивном вызове параметры n, from, to, free заменяются на новые.

Для примера вот такая простая рекурсивная функция:

    void foo(int n, int a, int b) {
        if(n!=0) {
            cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
            foo(n-1,b,a);
        }
    }

Вызываем вот так: foo(10,1,2); Что по-вашему будет выводиться на экран? По-моему 1 2 потом 2 1 потом 1 2 потом 2 1 и так пока n не станет равно 0. Рекурсивный вызов foo(n-1,b,a) каждый раз передает параметры a и b в другом порядке, чем было передано в данную функцию.

Comment: insolor, это шикарный пример, вы меня поняли. В принципе я это уже понял, только я не вижу здесь логики, хоть убей. НЕЛОГИЧНО. Вызываем
функцию void foo(n=10, a=1, b=2). В теле функции:
1 строка -- условие if. 
2 строка -- вывод: 1   2.
3 строка -- рекурсивный вызов(9, 2, 1). В теле рекурсивно вызванной функции: 
1 строка -- условие if.
2 строка -- вывод: 2   1.
3 строка -- рекурсивный вызов(8, 2, 1). 
Т. е. до конца стека(n-1, 2, 1). Но зацепка есть, ночью обмозгую,
 завтра напишу.

Comment: Что касается рекурсии, то самый, вероятно, прикольный набор примеров содержится в http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html , но, разумеется на haskell'е.

Comment: @Ключ, поправлю:

    0 строка -- параметры n=10, a=1, b=2
    1 строка -- условие if.
    2 строка -- вывод: 1 2.
    3 строка -- рекурсивный вызов(n=9, a=2, b=1).

    В теле рекурсивно вызванной функции:
    0 строка -- параметры n=9, a=2, b=1
    1 строка -- условие if.
    2 строка -- вывод: 2 1.
    3 строка -- рекурсивный вызов(n=8, a=1, b=2).

    0 строка -- параметры n=8, a=1, b=2
    ... (и так далее, но не до "конца стека", а пока n!=0

Comment: Добрый день. В любом рекурсивном вызове в скобках мы видим, что параметр n меняется, но в тех же скобках другие параметры и их комбинация неизменна, потому что комбинация параметров написана один раз и каждый рекурсионный вызов использует те параметры, которые в скобках и по логике они должны использоваться в функции
при каждом вызове одинаково(кроме n). Как в тело функции попадают другие или по другому расположенные параметры, чем те которые указаны в скобках при ее вызове?

..., но не до "конца стека", а пока n!=0 -- согласен.

Comment: Буквы те же, но значения у переменных, в т.ч. формальных параметров -- разные.

Comment: @Ключ, по аналогии с ООП, можно сказать что при рекурсивном вызове "создается" новый "экземпляр" функции со своими собственными параметрами и локальными переменными (на самом деле, в стеке просто выделяется память под параметры и переменные, тоже своего рода инкапсуляция). Параметры вызванной функции не являются параметрами вызывающей функции, т.к. хранятся в разных "ячейках" памяти (даже если функция "одна и та же").

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Третий день на этой странице у меня нет ссылки "комментировать", поэтому пишу "ответом". Insolor, ведь то, что вы написали в последнем комментарии подчиняется 
соответствующим правилам, алгоритму, какому то конкретному закону рекурсии, что ли. Вот я и хочу знать эти правила, что бы применив их, ясно представлять, что происходит. Пока нигде не нашел этого правила. Если можно, объясните пожалуйста: "...по аналогии с объектно ориентированным программированием, можно сказать...", в чем эта аналогия?
Спасибо.

Comment: Аналогия с ООП - в том, что как-бы создается новый "экземпляр" функции. Но это только аналогия.

Вроде бы нет никаких особых правил нет. Просто если функции foo была вызвана с параметрами 10,1,2 и вызывает "сама себя" с параметрами 9,2,1, то вызванный "экземпляр" получает именно эти параметры (9,2,1) и ничего не знает о параметрах (10,1,2), с которыми была вызвана предыдущая функция. Теперь она снова вызывает сама себя, но уже с параметрами (8,1,2) и снова вызванная функция ничего не знает ни о (10,1,2), ни даже о (9,2,1). Поэтому-то все работает именно так как работает:)

Comment: @Ключ, видимо Вы не до конца разобрались с вызовами функций (поэтому с рекурсией проблемы). Советую **попечатать** (на самом деле printf()) **адреса** параметров и **локальных переменных** функции при входе и сразу после возврата из рекурсивного вызова.

Посмотрите, как меняются циферки для одного и того же имени *и все сразу станет понятно*.

Comment: Добрый день. Аvp, я еще не познал, что такое 'printf()'. А другого 
способа разобраться с вызовами функций, в данном ключе нет? Я уже много перешерстил, по поводу именно вызовов функций, но пока ничего
нового, проясняющего, не нашел.

Comment: @Ключ, printf() это функция печати. См. (как всегда) man 3 printf. Если проблемы с использованием man, то читайте вывод man man. Там все написано.

Разобраться по другому, ну я не знаю, что именно Вам непонятно в рекурсивном вызове (почему @insolor начал говорить об аналогии с новым экземпляром объекта в ООП).

Скажем так, особенность в том, что именам параметров на каждом уровне рекурсии будут соответствовать новые адреса. Т.е. меняете, скажем, параметр x, а в вызывавшей активации этот параметр x не меняется (там у него другой адрес). 

Или это очевидно ?

Comment: Добрый день. Вроде начинаю понимать, надо прошерстить эту тему подробно(...новые адреса...).

И попробую по другому сформулировать, что мне непонятно было, на примере, что привел insolor:

void foo(int n=10, int a, int b) 
{ 
    if(n!=0) 
    { 
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl; 
        foo(n-1=9,b,a); 
    } 
}

Вызываем так: foo(10, 1, 2),

Что я вижу: 

после вызова    foo(n-1=9, b, a),

следующий вызов foo(n-1=8, b, a),

следующий вызов foo(n-1=7, b, a),

ведь такое расположение параметров указанно в скобках при вызове. Но в каждом новом вызове a и b меняются местами.

Comment: Но на самом деле, в каждом новом вызове a и b меняются местами.
Логично думать, что по очереди используются параметры самого первого вызова функции(нерекурсивного) и параметры рекурсивных вызовов, но если использовать параметры самого первого(нерекурсивного) вызова, то параметр n там всегда постоянный, но на самом деле каждый раз n уменьшается на единицу.

Comment: `Вызываем foo(10,1,2)
foo(n=10, a=1, b=2), вызывает foo(n-1=9, b=2, a=1)
foo(n=9, a=2, b=1), вызывает foo(n-1=8, b=1, a=2)` и т.д.

Comment: Не совсем понял Ваши рассуждения, например

    на самом деле, в каждом новом вызове a и b меняются местами.

Меняются местами с точки зрения очередной активации функции. На самом деле а и b в вызывающей функции не менялись местами. Где (по каким адресам памяти) они были, там и остались. **Их копии**, передаваемые в вызываемую процедуру меняются местами. Смотрите (в [] значения, после : адрес)

    foo (n:100[5], a:104[10], b:108[20])
        foo(n-1,b,a); // это вызов
        foo (n:84[4],a:88[20],b:92[10]) // это вход в foo()
            foo(n-1,b,a);

---- место кончилось ----

Comment: --- продолжим ---

          foo (n:68[3],a:72[10],b:76[20])

и т.д. Порисуйте сами. Стек растет в сторону уменьшения адресов, между  вызовами в него еще 4 байта адреса возврата кладут.

Comment: "Их копии, передаваемые в процедуру меняются местами", только я не вижу причин,обстоятельств, благодаря которым, копии вынуждены меняться местами.

Comment: Переписываем foo

    void foo(int n, int a, int b) {
        int w;
        if(n!=0) {
            cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
            w=a; a=b; b=w;
            foo(n-1,a,b);
        }
    }

Теперь меняются? Если да, то чем эта функция отличается от оригинала?
a теперь всегда 2й параметр, b-3й. Можно убрать обмен локальных a и b, но поменять их порядок в рекурсивном вызове.

Comment: Спасибо огромное alexlz за вот это:

Вызываем foo(10,1,2)

foo(n=10, a=1, b=2), вызывает foo(n-1=9, b=2, a=1)

foo(n=9, a=2, b=1), вызывает foo(n-1=8, b=1, a=2) и т.д.

Никак не могла понять как же значения между собой меняются местами, понимала, что это связано с перестановкой имен. я точно знала, что выводит на экран каждая функция, в точности понимала алгоритм решения. Но значения просто не хотели становиться на свои места. Рекурсию с факториалом и числами фибоначчи я поняла сразу, но именно эти башни просто не поддавались моему пониманию. Спасибо, что помогли прозреть!!!