# Какая формула у решения Ханойских башен с количеством столбцов больше трех?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык, логика

Стандартное решение - по формуле с 3 столбиками (2<sup>n</sup>-1). А есть ли вариант для иного количества столбцов, задаваемого пользователем?

Не могли бы вы предложить формулы для подобного рода расчетов оптимального количества ходов?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Непонятен алгоритм программы "Ханойские башни"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72364/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%a5%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Comment: Ваш ответ где-то тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8

Comment: @VladSpirin Здесь разбираются стандартные решения с 3 столбиками, будь-то рекурсивный метод или же итеративный метод, но не с указанным количеством столбиков

Comment: "Теория и практика строительства Ханойских башен." Жигалик С. Н.
ISBN 978-5-6041569-9-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая задача в общем виде решается при помощи графов - все состояния пирамидок можно представить в виде узлов графа, и искать кратчайший путь - например, поиском в ширину. Для небольших количеств колец и столбцов еще реально, но для сколь-нибудь ст*о*ящих - не сработает.

Задача в общем виде не решена. Есть такой алгоритм Фрейма — Стюарта, который дает *оптимальное* решение для четырёх (и *предположительно* оптимальное решение для большего количества) стержней:

Пусть `n` — количество дисков, `r` — число стержней.
`T(n,r)` - наименьшее число ходов, необходимое для переноса `n` дисков с использованием `r` стержней. Тогда можно применить рекурсию:

1. Для некоторого `1 ≤ k < n`, перенести верхние `k` дисков на стержень `i`, не являющийся ни начальным, ни конечным стержнем, затратив на это `T(k,r)` ходов.
2. Не используя стержень `i`, содержащий верхние `k` дисков, перенести оставшиеся `n−k` дисков на конечный стержень, используя только оставшиеся `r−1` стержней и затратив на это `T(n−k,r−1)` ходов.
3. Переместить верхние `k` дисков на конечный стержень, затратив на это `T(k,r)` ходов.

Итого требуется `2*T(k,r)+T(n−k,r−1)` ходов. Значение `k` выбирается таким, чтобы значение всего выражения было минимальным.

Для четырех стержней оптимальность доказана, для большего количества - нет, так что у вас есть шанс внести свой вклад :)

Вот [статейка](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~pkstoc/boca.ps) на эту тему.